# Magento blocks - still not getting it

Tags: magento, block

I have a custom template block (phtml) that is defined like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product" name="a.unique.name" template="dir/dir/customlist.phtml"/>
```

that is defined in CMS home page within this block

```
<reference name="left">
```

However if I move it to header block, it does not appear

```
<reference name="header">
```

What am I missing here?

** ---- addition -----

I tried this as suggested by D. Sloof, but it does not work.  (I suspect more due to my mis-actions than his explanation.)

I added getChildHtml('customlist'); ?> to

```
mytheme\template\page\html\header.phtml
```

just under div "top-col-1"

```
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="top-col-1">        
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customlist'); ?>
```

where "customlist" can befound in

```
mytheme/template/dir/dir/customlist.phtml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think "customlist" is the name of the block?

Comment: customlist.phtml is the name of my custom php template.

Comment: Note: Any mis-undertanding I have is not from reading Alan Storms blog at http://alanstorm.com/category/magento, but from not yet having bought his book!

Answer (score 1):

got it...

block name *a.unique.name* in xml file

```
<block type="catalog/product" name="a.unique.name" template="dir/dir/customlist.phtml"/>
```

must match what is called in mytheme\template\page\html\header.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('a.unique.name'); ?>
```

Comment: Correct in this case, but if the block had an alias (`<block ... as="some.alias" />`) you would use *that* instead. When no alias is provided, the name is used as the alias.

Answer (score 0):

The `header` block is of type `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` and will not automatically render child blocks. You can have a look at the template file `page/html/header.phtml` how the child block html is retrieved.

You essentially have 2 options:

- Add your own `getChildHtml` call in the header template (by copying it to your own theme), or;
- Put your block inside a container that will automatically render child blocks. The `left` block is of type `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` which will do this. There is a similar block inside the `header` block called `top.container` that is of type `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` that will do this as well: you can reference this block instead.